# Accessing named fields in a Haskell function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've defined a Tree data type in Haskell and an associated 'size' method which calculates the number of elements in the tree. This worked before, however I have updated the Tree data type to use named fields as in the following definition:

```
data Tree a = Empty
 | Leaf {value::a}
 | Node {left :: (Tree a), value :: a, right :: (Tree a)}
 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

I've found (by playing around in GHCi) that I can access a named field using the function (left n) for example. However, when I try to use this function I get an error:

```
size :: Tree a -> Int
size Empty    = 0
size (Leaf l)   = 1
size (Node n)   = size (left n) + 1 + size (right n)
```

GHCi simply says "Not in scope: left" and the equivalent for right. The Tree definition is in a module called Tree and the size definition is in a module called Main, but with the non-named fields I never had a problem with scope when it came to accessing variables from the Tree datatype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `size (Node n)` pattern needs to have a correct constructor. In your code `n` extracts the left element.

Try this (if you really want to use the named patterns):

```
size n@(Node _ _ _)   = size (left n) + 1 + size (right n)
```

Or even:

```
size n@(Node {})   = size (left n) + 1 + size (right n)
```

Or you can extract the labels in the pattern:

```
size (Node {left=l, right=r})   = size l + 1 + size r
```

or simply ignore the labels:

```
size (Node l _ r)   = size l + 1 + size r
```

Comment: I've tried all of your suggestions but I still get the 'not in scope' error. I can use 'left' and 'right' in GHCi but can't seem to use them in my Main module.

Comment: Are you exporting the names in your module? (Those names are functions too). You need something like "module TreeModule (Tree Node Leaf left right)" in your module code.

Comment: Thanks - I had omitted the left, right and value declarations from the code.

Comment: Or you could export like this: "module TreeModule (Tree(..))" which exports everything defined as part of the Tree data declaration.